# Standard for storing session key

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, cookies, local-storage

After doing a bit of research on this topic, it seems like session keys have typically been stored as cookies which is nice because they get automatically added to requests. I've been seeing that developers prefer localstorage to cookies due to less restrictions, though. I am building a React frontend, so persisting a reducer in localstorage and managing the session key in that reducer would be very easy. I would need to append this to requests, which seems to be the only downside. Wondering if there is a standard for how this should be done. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only a few places you can store your keys in the browser:

1. SessionStorage / LocalStorage
2. Cookies
3. Web workers
4. in memory

### Cookies

Cookies are one of the best places to put sensitive keys as long as it has the correct configurations/attributes with them. This includes, `httpOnly`, `secure`, `SameSite`, `Domain` and making sure they expire in a reasonable time. more reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) for how to set these attributes properly.

Cookies are good to use since they are as secure as HTTPS and cannot be accessed via javascript (if correct atrtibutes are set i.e httpOnly). But note there are still vulnerabilities you have to watch out for such as a CSRF attack, and you would have to include a CSRF token to counter this vulnerability since the cookie gets added to the headers automatically by the browser.

### LocalStorage / SessionStorage

LocalStorage and session storage are poor places to keep keys since they are accessible via javascript. You can look [here](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/token-storage) on how Auth0 recommends to store keys, and note they persuade not to store it in localStorage for said reasons.

### In Memory

You can store the key in javascript memory (use a closure to encapsulate your key). This has a downside as the key will not persist after refresh/close/new tab etc but is still pretty secure

### Web Workers

[Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) are another place you can store the key. Workers run in a separate global scope than the rest of the application so it keeps them pretty secure, and you can have fine grain control as to what apis to send they key to.

Auth can be tricky and it can be easy to forget to include something important, so make sure you are well read on all attributes and how each piece works. Or go with a pre made options like Auth0 or single sing-on.